# How to rewrite mockControl test to spring 4

Tags: java, spring, testing

In spring 3.6 I am testing client side according to this example: http://javacrumbs.net/spring-ws-test/

Problem is this doesn work with spring 4. It throw exception:

```
java.lang.IncompatibleClassChangeError: Found interface org.springframework.test.context.TestContext, but class was expected
    at net.javacrumbs.springws.test.simple.annotation.WsMockControlTestExecutionListener.prepareTestInstance(WsMockControlTestExecutionListener.java:47)
    at org.springframework.test.context.TestContextManager.prepareTestInstance(TestContextManager.java:331)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.createTest(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:213)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner$1.runReflectiveCall(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:290)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.methodBlock(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:292)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:233)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:87)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:193)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:52)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:191)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:42)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:184)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunBeforeTestClassCallbacks.java:61)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.statements.RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.evaluate(RunAfterTestClassCallbacks.java:71)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.springframework.test.context.junit4.SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.run(SpringJUnit4ClassRunner.java:176)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:50)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:467)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:683)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:390)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:197)
```

how should I rewrite this test to spring 4 ?

Answer (score 0):

First I try to debug this error with some more information so I create class:

```
import net.javacrumbs.springws.test.simple.annotation.WsMockControlTestExecutionListener;
import net.javacrumbs.springws.test.util.MockMessageSenderInjector;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.config.ConfigurableListableBeanFactory;
import org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.test.context.TestContext;

public class WsMockControlTestExecutionSpring4Listener extends WsMockControlTestExecutionListener {

    private static final String MESSAGE_SENDER_BEAN_NAME = "net.javacrumbs.springws.test.simple.annotation.WsMockControlMockWebServiceMessageSender";
    private static final String MOCK_CONTROL_BEAN_NAME = "net.javacrumbs.springws.test.simple.annotation.WsMockControl";

    @Override
    public void prepareTestInstance(TestContext testContext) throws Exception {
        ConfigurableListableBeanFactory beanFactory = ((AbstractApplicationContext) testContext.getApplicationContext())
                .getBeanFactory();

        if (!beanFactory.containsBean(MOCK_CONTROL_BEAN_NAME)) {
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(MOCK_CONTROL_BEAN_NAME, createWsMockControlFactoryBean());
            beanFactory.registerSingleton(MESSAGE_SENDER_BEAN_NAME, createMessageSender());
            new MockMessageSenderInjector().postProcessBeanFactory(beanFactory);
        }

    }
}
```

and in test I used this listener:

```
@TestExecutionListeners({ WsMockControlTestExecutionSpring4Listener.class,
        DependencyInjectionTestExecutionListener.class })
```

and now the weird part. Tests are again working but I really dont understand why. I did nothing. Just override method `prepareTestInstance` with the exactly same code as in `WsMockControlTestExecutionListener`. Can someone explain me this "solution"